# Where I can find a repository of iPhone images?

Tags: iphone, icons, uitabview

There are a lot of things I'm bad at, but drawing probably tops the list.

I'm looking for a decent size repository for iPhone tab icons. Something similar to Wikimedia commons (I ask this as I'm waiting for fink and GIMP to install). Any suggestions out there?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I rate the [Glyphish collection](http://glyphish.com/) of icons and have used them in several projects.